# How to check if the text fields are filled then change the color of the button?

Tags: flutter, dart

Need help with code. I have a registration page and I'm doing a check when there is an empty field (not filled in by the user) - the button doesn't fire. But I also want to do when there is one non-empty field, then the color of the button is gray, but when all the fields are filled, the color of the button is changed to purple. I tried to do this (use `isButtonEnabled`) but the button itself does not change color when all the fields are filled. Tell me how to implement this function so that it is controlled when the fields are all non-empty, the color of the button is purple, and when the fields are empty - gray?

**contollers**

```
EmailSignUpWidget(
   size: size * 0.42,
   nameEditingController: _nameEditingControllerReg,
   passwordEditingController: _passwordEditingControllerReg,
   emailEditingController: _emailEditingControllerReg,
  )
```

**button**

```
DefaultButtonGlow(
                                        text: isSignUp ? 'Sign Up' : 'Next',
                                        color: isButtonEnabled ? constants.Colors.purpleMain : constants.Colors.grey,
                                        onPressed: () async {
                                          if ((_nameEditingControllerReg.text
                                                      .trim() !=
                                                  "") &&
                                              (_passwordEditingControllerReg
                                                      .text
                                                      .trim() !=
                                                  "") &&
                                              (_emailEditingControllerReg.text
                                                      .trim() !=
                                                  "")) {
                                            _onTap(unauthUserCubit, tokenCubit);
                                            isButtonEnabled = true;
                                          } else {
                                            isButtonEnabled = false;
                                          }
                                        },
                                        shadowColor:
                                            constants.Colors.purpleMain,
                                        textStyle: constants
                                            .Styles.normalHeavyTextStyleWhite,
                                      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed should use the onChanged property. However, it takes a bit more to make sure several use cases are covered.

Use case: User removes text from the TextField. Action: button should become gray again.

Create a boolean for each TextField that is required to be filled before button becomes purple.

```
bool textField1Filled = false;
bool textField2Filled = false;
bool textField3Filled = false;
```

In each TextField widget you have the following onChanged:

```
onChanged: (content) {
    if (content != "") {
        textField1Filled = true;
        if (textField1Filled && textField2Filled && textField3Filled) {
            setState((){isButtonEnabled = true;});
            }
        } else {
            textField1Filled = false;
            setState((){isButtonEnabled = false;});
        }
  },
)
```

Comment: Okay, I'll try your solution a little later and give you an answer.

Comment: Tell me, why after else you also have the value true, maybe you made a mistake and you need to specify false there?

Comment: yes, small mistake, thanks for noticing. Changed it

Comment: I do not understand the reason, but for some reason it does not work

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TextField or TextFormField, I think you need to use **onChanged** property.

when it changes, check string is empty or you can put changes based on that.

```
TextField(
controller: textEditController,
onChanged: (content) {
 
  },
)
```

Comment: and here add the setState method in which I will change the value of the isButtonEnabled variable, right?

Comment: yes. try it and confirm.